# Spring boot app connection refused when connecting to postgresql server in docker

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am learning to use docker and I have a problem where my spring boot app tries to connect to the postgresql db through the local host instead of the network created through docker-compose.
Here is my applicaton.yaml file:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        show_sql: true
        format_sql: true
  datasource:
    platform: postgres
    url: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/springbootexercise
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    image: nedbro/springbootfrontend
    container_name: frontend
    expose:
      - "80"
    ports:
    - 9090:80
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=springexercise
    restart: unless-stopped
  springbootapp:
    image: nedbro/springbootbackend
    container_name: springbootapp
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
```

This is the error message I get when the spring container starts:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Why is it trying to access the postgresql server through the local host? Or maybe I have missed something in the docker compose file?

**EDIT**
I have got the solution, the problem was that I only ran mvn clean and not mvn package when I made changes to the application.yaml file, so that's why it wanted to connect to the localhost.

Comment: why your application is connecting to to localhost:5432

Comment: I am not an expert of docker compose but I think you have to define a network and connect your apps to that network

Comment: Thank for the help, I have got the solution, check  the edit I made to the original question.